# State processing in pyspark structured settlement

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am running a simple logic in pyspark structured streaming.

I have n events for each id
These events come in or out of order and continuously from a kafka topic.

I have to apply a logic where if event of id '123' comes check if it is final event, if it is final then process all events with that id. I need to wait for all the events of this id to perform calculation.

Sample Dataset:

| Id | eventtype | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | load | 22 |
| 123 | data | 32 |
| 123 | unload | 20 |

I have to group by id 123 and result should have average of all events. But I need to wait for unload event .

Result:

| Id | eventtype | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | aggregate | 24.75 |

How can I achieve this
Using a state store?
Using some window?

Please explain the approach with an example.

Comment: Please provide sample dataset and expected output.

Comment: Sample dataset
[Id, eventtype, value ] -> values
(123, load, 22), (124, data, 32) (123, unload, 20).  Now i have to group by id 123 and result should have average of all events. But i need to wait for unload event . So result -> (123, aggregate, 24.75)